# Extract academic publication information from IDEAS

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the list of publications from a specific [IDEAS's page](https://ideas.repec.org/s/rtr/wpaper.html). I want to retrieve information about name of the paper, authors, and year. However, I am bit stuck in doing so. By inspecting the page, all information is inside the `div class="tab-pane fade show active" [...]`, then with `h3` we do have the year of publication while inside each `li class="list-group-item downfree" [...]` we can find each paper with relative author (as showed in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUQDo.jpg)). At the end, what I willing to obtain is a dataframe containing three columns: title, author, and year.

Nonetheless, while I am able to retrieve each paper's name, when I want to add also year and author(s) I get confused. What I wrote so far is the following short code:

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://ideas.repec.org/s/rtr/wpaper.html'
response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'tab-pane fade show active'})

title_list = []
year_list = []

for container in containers:

    year = container.findAll('h3')
    year_list.append(int(year[0].text))

    title_containers = container.findAll("li", {'class': 'list-group-item downfree'})
    title = title_containers[0].a.text
    title_list.append(title)
```

What I get are two list of only one element each. This because the initial containers has the size of 1. Regarding instead how to retrieve author(s) name I have no idea, I tried in several ways without success. I think I have to stripe the titles using 'by' as separator.

I hope someone could help me or re-direct to some other discussion which face a similar situation. Thank you in advance. Apologize for my (probably) silly question, I am still a beginner in web scraping with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired information like this:

```
from requests import get
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ideas.repec.org/s/rtr/wpaper.html'
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
container = soup.select_one("#content")
title_list = []
author_list = []
year_list = [int(h.text) for h in container.find_all('h3')]
for panel in container.select("div.panel-body"):
    title_list.append([x.text for x in panel.find_all('a')])
    author_list.append([x.next_sibling.strip() for x in panel.find_all('i')])
result = list(zip(year_list, title_list, author_list))

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=250)
pp.pprint(result)
```

outputs:

```
[   (   2020,
        ['The Role Of Public Procurement As Innovation Lever: Evidence From Italian Manufacturing Firms', 'A voyage in the role of territory: are territories capable of instilling their peculiarities in local production systems'],
        ['Francesco Crespi & Serenella Caravella', 'Cristina Vaquero-Piñeiro']),
    (   2019,
        [   'Probability Forecasts and Prediction Markets',
            'R&D Financing And Growth',
            'Mission-Oriented Innovation Policies: A Theoretical And Empirical Assessment For The Us Economy',
            'Public Investment Fiscal Multipliers: An Empirical Assessment For European Countries',
            'Consumption Smoothing Channels Within And Between Households',
            'A critical analysis of the secular stagnation theory',
            'Further evidence of the relationship between social transfers and income inequality in OECD countries',
            'Capital accumulation and corporate portfolio choice between liquidity holdings and financialisation'],
        [   'Julia Mortera & A. Philip Dawid',
            'Luca Spinesi & Mario Tirelli',
            'Matteo Deleidi & Mariana Mazzucato',
            'Enrico Sergio Levrero & Matteo Deleidi & Francesca Iafrate',
            'Simone Tedeschi & Luigi Ventura & Pierfederico Asdrubal',
            'Stefano Di Bucchianico',
            "Giorgio D'Agostino & Luca Pieroni & Margherita Scarlato",
            'Giovanni Scarano']),
    (   2018, ...
```

I got the years using a list comprehension. I got the titles and authors by appending a list to the title_list  and title_list for the required elements in each div element with the class `panel-body` again using a list comprehension and using next.sibling for the `i` element to get the authors. Then I zipped the three lists and cast the result to a list. Finally I pretty printed the result.

Comment: i liked that way